# Why doesn't jQuery remove work for dynamically added rows?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery.

Would you guys know why the `.remove()` doesn't work for the rows that are added using the `add` button? It works otherwise for the already existing elements such as `<li>One</li>`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.more').click(function(){
                html_frag='<li>XXX<input type="submit" value="Remove" class="testing" /></li>';
                $('ul li:last').after(html_frag);
                return false;
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.testing').click(function(){
                $(this).remove();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            One
            <input type="submit" value="Remove" class="testing" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="more" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the newly added elements doesn't exist on DOM when you bind that handler. Try using delegated events like below,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.testing', function(){
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
 });
```

Comment: If possible, use a tighter scope than `document`, for efficiency.

Comment: @Brad Well unfortunately his html didn't had any container

Comment: Right, I'm saying for his benefit, if he has something else to attach the handler to, it would be better.

Comment: A related question. Lets say, the event I have to watch out for is not click related. Lets say the event is the addition of another node (eg. an input element). How then do I go about using `on`? I understand that events such as `DOMNodeInserted` etc. are not recommended to be used due to performance issues. In this case, what exactly should I do?

Comment: Ok I see that there are jQuery plugins such as `livequery` that can help with this. Is this the way it is generally done or am I not going in the right direction?

Comment: @George This is how it is done.. and you can find them in jQuery documentations http://api.jquery.com/on/ > Section Delegated Events

Answer (score 0):

try this ,it doesn't work because you are creating element dynamically, for dynamically created element use on or live of jquery.

```
   $("body").on("click", ".testing", function(event){
      $(this).remove();
          return false;
   });
```

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated a long time ago.  I don't recommend recommending using it.

Comment: may depend on user using jquery library if using old one than what?

Comment: Your suggestion that someone "new to jQuery" and clearly creating a first project with it would go back and get a 2-3 year old version of jQuery for this project is ridiculous.  In any case, do not recommend using deprecated functions!  If you have to for some reason, such as someone working on an existing project, you need to mention in your post that the method is deprecated.  You didn't, so I added a comment alerting future readers.

Comment: sorry for that next time ,I will